# How to count how many customers have purchase a product in SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I have a C# application that displays products that a company sells. Next to that column is the product type and in the last column is the number of customers that have bought that product. This is my SQL query to populate the first two columns:

```
string selectQuery;
selectQuery = "SELECT Products.ProductID, Products.ProductTypeID, ";
selectQuery = selectQuery + "Products.ProductName, Products.YearlyPremium, ProductTypes.ProductType ";
selectQuery = selectQuery + "FROM Products ";
selectQuery = selectQuery + "INNER JOIN ProductTypes ON Products.ProductTypeID = ProductTypes.ProductTypeID "
```

Now I need to work out how many customers bought each product. I guess I need to use the `COUNT(*)` method to get CustomerID's but now sure how to integrate it into this query.
Here is the schema
[image]

The code I use to display the data in the listView is this:

```
SqlConnection conn = ConnectionsManager.DatabaseConnection();
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Products product = new Products(int.Parse(rdr["ProductID"].ToString()),
                                     int.Parse(rdr["ProductTypeID"].ToString()),
                                     rdr["ProductName"].ToString(),
                                     Math.Round(decimal.Parse(rdr["YearlyPremium"].ToString()), 2));
                ProductTypes productType = new ProductTypes(int.Parse(rdr["ProductTypeID"].ToString()),
                                     rdr["ProductType"].ToString());

                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(product.ProductName.ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(productType.ProductType.ToString());
                \\lvi.SubItems.Add(customer.CustomerID.ToString()); <---this will be the line to display the customer count
                lvMain.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
            if (rdr != null)
                rdr.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unsuccessful" + ex);
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a `mysql` question :)?

Comment: Find count of customerid for each productid from sales table itself.

Comment: This is not a free code writing service. We're more than happy to help, but you're expected to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. When you've done so and run into difficulties, you can explain the problem you've encountered, include the relevant portions of your code, and ask a specific question related to that code, and we'll try to help. From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking for homework help **must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it**.*

Answer (score 0):

Considering that ProductTypeId is has to be a NON NULL value in final result (hence using INNER JOIN), the SQL part which you will have to embed in your C# code:

```
SELECT  P.ProductID, P.ProductTypeID, P.ProductName, P.YearlyPremium, PT.ProductType, CustomerCount = COUNT(S.CustomerID)
FROM    Sales S
        INNER JOIN Products P
           ON S.ProductID = P.ProductID
        INNER JOIN ProductTypes PT 
           ON P.ProductTypeID = PT.ProductTypeID 
GROUP   BY P.ProductID, P.ProductTypeID, P.ProductName, P.YearlyPremium, PT.ProductType
```

Note:- Since you do not need any attribute of the customer, and you have a foreign key on Sales.CustomerID column to Customer.CustomerId column, hence for the purpose of getting the CustomerCount, join to Customer table is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

try using Group by clause. It will work.
**Example:**

```
SELECT COUNT(ProductId),CustomerId
FROM Product
GROUP BY CustomerId;
```

kind of this

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want a basic `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.ProductTypeID, p.ProductName, p.YearlyPremium,
       pt.ProductType,
       COUNT(DISTINCT s.CustomerID) as num_customers
FROM Products p INNER JOIN
     ProductTypes pt
     ON p.ProductTypeID = PT.ProductTypeID LEFT JOIN
     Sales S
     ON s.ProductID = p.ProductID 
GROUP BY p.ProductID, p.ProductTypeID, p.ProductName, p.YearlyPremium, pt.ProductType;
```

Notes:

- This uses a `LEFT JOIN` to `Sales` to get products that have no sales.
- This uses an `INNER JOIN` to `ProductTypes` because, presumably, all products have a type.
- The `GROUP BY` has all non-aggregated columns.
- This counts unique customer ids, because the same customer may have purchased the same product on more than one occasion.  If you just want a count of the records in `Sales`, remove the `DISTINCT`.